# how can I copy and delete only the files base of modified date in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

all files from my source file location has been copied in 
destination folder. 
how can i copy then delete the 2 files only if my 
datefrom = 12/07/2014 and my 
dateto = 12/09/2014.

- filename:  date modified
- file1       12/07/2014
- file2       12/09/2014
- file3       01/06/2015

this is my code.

```
    Dim ObjFso 
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim StrSourceLocation
    Dim StrDestinationLocation
    Dim StrSourceFileName  
    dim SourceLocation
    dim DestinationLocation
    dim datefrom, dateto, datectr
    datefrom = DateValue("01/01/2015")
    dateto = DateValue("01/01/2015")

    datefrom = InputBox ("date from: (mm/dd/yyyy)")
    dateto = InputBox ("date to: (mm/dd/yyyy)")
    StrSourceLocation = InputBox ("source:")
    StrDestinationLocation = InputBox ("destination:")

    datectr = datefrom
    dateto = dateto
    intYear=0
    intMonth=0
    indDay=0
    intFileCtr=0
    intFileDayCtr=0


    SourceLocation = StrSourceLocation + "\*.*"
    DestinationLocation = StrDestinationLocation + "\"

    Const OverwriteExisting = True

    Do Until datectr>dateto

    intYear=Year(datectr)
    intMonth=Month(datectr)
    intDay=Day(datectr)


    for each f in objFSO.Getfolder(StrSourceLocation).Files

    if Year(f.DateLastModified) = intYear And Month(f.DatelastModified) = intMonth And Day(f.DateLastModified) = intDay Then

    objFSO.CopyFile SourceLocation , DestinationLocation, OverwriteExisting
    objFSO.DeleteFile(SourceLocation), True

    end if
    Next

datectr=DateAdd("d", 1, datectr)
datectr = DateValue(datectr)

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are doing. Dates are simple in VBS.

```
If DateValue("01/01/1980") < DateValue("01/01/1990") or DateValue("01/01/1980") > DateValue("01/01/1960") then

' blah
End If
```

Is how to check dates within a range.

There is also the similar `DateSerial`. Dates are numbers, x days since a day in the past (01/01/100 AD) with time being a a fraction which is a fraction of a day (12 pm is 0.5).

Comment: i have series of files sir, example: file1 file2 and file3. i want to copy only file 1 and file 2 in the destination folder and delete the file 1 and file2 in source folder. so file3 will be left in the source folder and file1 and file2 has been moved to destination folder. But the 3 files has been copied in destination folder and deleted the 3 files in source folder.

Comment: Hi sir.. I think I solved the problem..








objFSO.CopyFile f , DestinationLocation, OverwriteExisting
objFSO.DeleteFile(f), True